# is there a way to change the default windows proxy settings from commandline?

Tags: windows, shell, proxy, settings

I basically want to set my windows proxy by letting my program issue a shell command to do so. is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

`netsh winhttp set proxy myproxy:3128`